# ASP.NET: Sending E-Mail after Gridview Row Inserted

Tags: asp.net, gridview, insert, devexpress, row

I have a two table like this;

```
Table Name: PROSPECT // Columns --> (CUSTOMER, YAT_ADET, FILO)
```

---

```
Table Name: TEMSILCI // Columns --> (CUSTOMER, MAIL)
```

Basicly, When I Inserted to `Gridview` 3 data for `PROSPECT` table, I want to send an e-mail to `CUSTOMER`. But Mail address data in `TEMSILCI` table. So, I should get, after the row inserted, CUSTOMER's mail address.

My SqlDataSource's `InsertCommand` is;

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO PROSPECT(CUSTOMER, YAT_ADET, FILO) VALUES (@CUSTOMER, @YAT_ADET, @FILO)"
```

I think, my scenario should;

1. Get the CUSTOMER value which inserted to `Gridview`.
2. Execute and get mail address with query like `SELECT MAIL FROM TEMSILCI WHERE CUSTOMER = 'Inserted CUSTOMER'`
3. After that, apply mail address to my already written `SendMail()` function.

I'm thinking to use  [`RowInserted`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowInsertedtopic) Event.

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_RowInserted(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But how can I exactly do step `1` and `2` ? **AND**, How can I get SqlDataSource Inserted parameter's value programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
protected void SqlDataSource11_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
      string yatplan = cmd.Parameters["@YAT_PLAN"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

This code getting inserted value of `YAT_PLAN` column to `ASPxGridview`.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the newly inserted data record's ID via the [SCOPE_IDENTITY / @@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function and combine a required email message. Refer to the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q299244 discussion in the DevExpress support center. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand your answer. How scope_identity will help me? OR What should I execute a query in my `ASPxGridView1_RowInserted` function?

Comment: Would you share part of the ASPxGridView / DataSource control markup here?

Comment: I found the solution. Check my answer. Thanks for support!